# HierarchicalDataTemplate [WPF]

Tags: c#, wpf, sql-server, entity-framework

Есть 2 таблицы в MS SQL Server. Нужно получить Tree View такого вида:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я получаю данные из таблиц используя Entity Framework. 
Код Context'a:

```
public partial class MSGContext : DbContext
{
    public MSGContext()
        : base("name=MSGContext")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<article> article { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<section> section { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<article>()
            .Property(e => e.articleName)
            .IsFixedLength();

        modelBuilder.Entity<section>()
            .Property(e => e.sectionName)
            .IsFixedLength();

        modelBuilder.Entity<section>()
            .HasMany(e => e.article)
            .WithRequired(e => e.section)
            .HasForeignKey(e => e.articleSection)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

Модель таблицы article:

```
[Table("article")]
public partial class article
{
    public int articleId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(200)]
    public string articleName { get; set; }

    public int articleSection { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string articleText { get; set; }

    public byte[] articlePhoto { get; set; }

    public virtual section section { get; set; }
}
```

Модель таблицы section:

```
[Table("section")]
public partial class section
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public section()
    {
        article = new HashSet<article>();
    }

    public int sectionId { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100)]
    public string sectionName { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    public virtual ICollection<article> article { get; set; }
}
```

Схема базы данных:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Каким образом можно заполнить Tree View используя HierarchicalDataTemplate?

Comment: Этот код создан автоматически при использовании Entity Framework Code First из существующей базы данных.

Comment: Извиняюсь, невнимательно прочитал ваш код.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

xaml:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <DataTemplate x:Key="ArticleTemplate">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding articleName}"/>
    </DataTemplate>

    <HierarchicalDataTemplate x:Key="SectionTemplate"
                          ItemsSource="{Binding article}"
                          ItemTemplate="{StaticResource ArticleTemplate}">
        <TextBlock Text="{Binding sectionName}" />
    </HierarchicalDataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<TreeView x:Name="tv" ItemsSource="{Binding}" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource SectionTemplate}"/>
```

Заполнение TreeView:

```
MSGContext db = new MSGContext();
tv.DataContext = db.section.ToList();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]